# SDL window shows incorrectly. On linux terminal

Tags: c++, image, sdl

This is basically my code here, very simple just to load an image to display. But the first thing I open a window surface, the surface has characters like 'X','S' out of nowhere:

[image]

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
  SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );

  SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0,
                                          SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF );
  SDL_WM_SetCaption( WINDOW_TITLE, 0 );
  SDL_Surface* bitmap = SDL_LoadBMP("bat.bmp");

  // Part of the bitmap that we want to draw                                                                  
  SDL_Rect source;
  source.x = 24;
  source.y = 63;
  source.w = 65;
  source.h = 44;

  // Part of the screen we want to draw the sprite to                                                         
  SDL_Rect destination;
  destination.x = 100;
  destination.y = 100;
  destination.w = 65;
  destination.h = 44;




  SDL_Event event;
  bool gameRunning = true;
  int i=1000;
  while (i)
    {
      if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
          if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
              gameRunning = false;
            }
        }
      SDL_BlitSurface(bitmap, &source, screen, &destination);
      SDL_Flip(screen);
      i--;
    }

  SDL_FreeSurface(bitmap);
  SDL_Quit();


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And that looks nothing like your bitmap? And you still get that even if you comment out the `SDL_BlitSurface` line?

Comment: Yes  even if I just show the empty window without the bitmap thing, it still gets these characters on the background. Is that due to the SDL setting up things or something concerning my terminal display option?

Comment: SDL1 is [unmaintained](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SourceCode#SDL_1.2_.28obsolete.2Flegacy.29).  Can you repro with SDL2?